# Unity Crash when entering Play Mode - Unity XR VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, oculus, unity-xr

Unity is crashing when entering the play mode.

- This does not happen if my Quest 2 is connected to Unity
- I use the Open / Oculuus XR Plugins
- I use the Sample Controller example with some custom code
- Attached to this, you may find the Input

Does any of you have similar issues? How to best debug this error? It could have something to do with finding the device when none is connected, but I could not find anything.

```
[..]
[00:00:05] Finished 1 Bake Runtime job (0.24s execute, 0.00s integrate, 0.25s wallclock)
[Optix] Number of Devices = 1
[Optix] context local device 0: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU - 6143MB VRAM (available: 4638MB)
[Optix] successfully set up context.
[Optix] removing context.
[00:00:08] Bake took 3.195458 seconds.
[PathTracer] Loaded OpenRL shaders in 3.234 secs -> Timestamps: [76.772 - 80.006].
[PathTracer] Total bake time: 0.021025, raw bake time: 0.000000
[00:00:12] Builtin Sky manager started.
[00:00:12] Finished 1 Bake Ambient Probe job (0.01s execute, 0.00s integrate, 0.25s wallclock)
[00:00:13] LightingDataAsset started.
> Collecting Enlighten data
Asset Pipeline Refresh: Total: 0.065 seconds - Initiated by RefreshV2(AllowForceSynchronousImport)
[OVRPlugin][INFO] UnityPluginLoad calledTrimDiskCacheJob: Current cache size 10mb
Asset Pipeline Refresh: Total: 0.016 seconds - Initiated by RefreshV2(AllowForceSynchronousImport)
C:\build\output\Unity-Technologies\mono\mono\eglib\gpath.c:115: assertion 'filename != NULL' failed

Asset Pipeline Refresh: Total: 0.013 seconds - Initiated by RefreshV2(AllowForceSynchronousImport)
Asset Pipeline Refresh: Total: 0.064 seconds - Initiated by RefreshV2(AllowForceSynchronousImport)
Asset Pipeline Refresh: Total: 0.062 seconds - Initiated by RefreshV2(AllowForceSynchronousImport)
Asset Pipeline Refresh: Total: 0.016 seconds - Initiated by RefreshV2(AllowForceSynchronousImport)
Reloading assemblies for play mode.
Registering precompiled user dll's ...
Registered in 0.044125 seconds.
Reloading assemblies after forced synchronous recompile.
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Symbol file LoadedFromMemory doesn't match image C:\SaltyVR\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.visualscripting@1.7.8\Editor\VisualScripting.Core\Dependencies\DotNetZip\Unity.VisualScripting.IonicZip.dll
Symbol file LoadedFromMemory doesn't match image C:\SaltyVR\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.visualscripting@1.7.8\Editor\VisualScripting.Core\Dependencies\YamlDotNet\Unity.VisualScripting.YamlDotNet.dll
Native extension for WindowsStandalone target not found
Native extension for Android target not found
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 427.77 ms, found 19 plugins.
Preloading 1 native plugins for Editor in 0.41 ms.
[MODES] ModeService[none].Initialize
[MODES] ModeService[none].LoadModes
[MODES] Loading mode Default (0) for mode-current-id-Salty VR
Mono: successfully reloaded assembly
- Completed reload, in  6.759 seconds
Domain Reload Profiling:
    ReloadAssembly (6761ms)
        BeginReloadAssembly (3400ms)
            ExecutionOrderSort (2ms)
            DisableScriptedObjects (129ms)
            BackupInstance (0ms)
            ReleaseScriptingObjects (2ms)
            CreateAndSetChildDomain (537ms)
        EndReloadAssembly (3277ms)
            LoadAssemblies (3048ms)
            RebuildTransferFunctionScriptingTraits (1ms)
            SetupTypeCache (304ms)
            ReleaseScriptCaches (7ms)
            RebuildScriptCaches (108ms)
            SetupLoadedEditorAssemblies (1516ms)
                LogAssemblyErrors (0ms)
                InitializePlatformSupportModulesInManaged (14ms)
                SetLoadedEditorAssemblies (0ms)
                RefreshPlugins (428ms)
                BeforeProcessingInitializeOnLoad (185ms)
                ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes (768ms)
                ProcessInitializeOnLoadMethodAttributes (115ms)
                AfterProcessingInitializeOnLoad (4ms)
                EditorAssembliesLoaded (1ms)
            ExecutionOrderSort2 (0ms)
            AwakeInstancesAfterBackupRestoration (574ms)
Platform modules already initialized, skipping
Registering precompiled user dll's ...
Registered in 0.008288 seconds.
Asset Pipeline Refresh: Total: 8.204 seconds - Initiated by StopAssetImportingV2(ForceSynchronousImport | ForceDomainReload)
    Summary:
        Imports: total=0 (actual=0, local cache=0, cache server=0)
        Asset DB Process Time: managed=0 ms, native=1188 ms
        Asset DB Callback time: managed=26 ms, native=0 ms
        Scripting: domain reloads=1, domain reload time=6984 ms, compile time=4 ms, other=0 ms
        Project Asset Count: scripts=10869, non-scripts=5325
        Asset File Changes: new=0, changed=0, moved=0, deleted=0
        Scan Filter Count: 0
    InvokeBeforeRefreshCallbacks: 0.290ms
    ApplyChangesToAssetFolders: 0.071ms
    Scan: 0.000ms
    OnSourceAssetsModified: 0.000ms
    InitializeImportedAssetsSnapshot: 97.279ms
    GetAllGuidsForCategorization: 64.443ms
    CategorizeAssets: 863.487ms
    ImportOutOfDateAssets: 7011.450ms (7001.179ms without children)
        CompileScripts: 3.970ms
        EnsureUptoDateAssetsAreRegisteredWithGuidPM: 3.344ms
        InitializingProgressBar: 0.002ms
        PostProcessAllAssetNotificationsAddChangedAssets: 1.696ms
        OnDemandSchedulerStart: 1.260ms
    ReloadSourceAssets: 10.377ms
    UnloadImportedAssets: 3.795ms
    PostProcessAllAssets: 26.456ms
    GatherAllCurrentPrimaryArtifactRevisions: 0.625ms
    UnloadStreamsBegin: 0.097ms
    LoadedImportedAssetsSnapshotReleaseGCHandles: 3.789ms
    GetLoadedSourceAssetsSnapshot: 15.991ms
    PersistCurrentRevisions: 0.607ms
    UnloadStreamsEnd: 0.100ms
    GenerateScriptTypeHashes: 24.137ms
    Untracked: 131.541ms
The referenced script (Unknown) on this Behaviour is missing!
The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '--- WeaponScripts') is missing!
[Subsystems] OculusXRPlugin successfully registered Provider for oculus input
[Subsystems] OculusXRPlugin successfully registered Provider for oculus display
[Subsystems] OpenXR XR Plugin successfully registered Provider for OpenXR Display
[Subsystems] OculusXRPlugin successfully registered Provider for oculus input
[Subsystems] OculusXRPlugin successfully registered Provider for oculus display
[Subsystems] OpenXR XR Plugin successfully registered Provider for OpenXR Input
[Subsystems] OpenXR XR Plugin successfully registered Provider for OpenXR Display
[OculusXRFeature] HookGetInstanceProcAddr: 140733545404274
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Oculus.XR.OculusXRFeature:HookGetInstanceProcAddr (intptr) (at Assets/Oculus/VR/Scripts/OculusXRFeature.cs:118)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.Features.OpenXRFeature:HookGetInstanceProcAddr () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/Features/OpenXRFeature.cs:676)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase:InitializeInternal () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/OpenXRLoader.cs:225)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase:Initialize () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/OpenXRLoader.cs:183)
UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRManagerSettings:InitializeLoaderSync () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@4.2.1/Runtime/XRManagerSettings.cs:190)
UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRGeneralSettings:InitXRSDK () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@4.2.1/Runtime/XRGeneralSettings.cs:175)
UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRGeneralSettings:AttemptInitializeXRSDKOnLoad () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@4.2.1/Runtime/XRGeneralSettings.cs:148)

(Filename: Assets/Oculus/VR/Scripts/OculusXRFeature.cs Line: 118)

[OculusXRFeature] SetClientVersion
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Oculus.XR.OculusXRFeature:HookGetInstanceProcAddr (intptr) (at Assets/Oculus/VR/Scripts/OculusXRFeature.cs:120)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.Features.OpenXRFeature:HookGetInstanceProcAddr () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/Features/OpenXRFeature.cs:676)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase:InitializeInternal () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/OpenXRLoader.cs:225)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase:Initialize () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/OpenXRLoader.cs:183)
UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRManagerSettings:InitializeLoaderSync () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@4.2.1/Runtime/XRManagerSettings.cs:190)
UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRGeneralSettings:InitXRSDK () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@4.2.1/Runtime/XRGeneralSettings.cs:175)
UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRGeneralSettings:AttemptInitializeXRSDKOnLoad () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@4.2.1/Runtime/XRGeneralSettings.cs:148)

(Filename: Assets/Oculus/VR/Scripts/OculusXRFeature.cs Line: 120)

[OVRPlugin][INFO] UnityOpenXR_SetClientVersion(1, 79, 0) called[OVRPlugin][INFO] ovrp_UnityOpenXR_HookGetInstanceProcAddr(00007FFF14FB5772)[OVRPlugin][INFO] CompositorOpenXR::PreInitialize(activity = 0000000000000000, apiType = 0, preinitializeFlags=0x1)[OVRPlugin][INFO]  -- Set xrGetInstanceProcAddr to external function pointer[OVRPlugin][INFO] Available Layers: (0)[OVRPlugin][INFO] Preinitialize: xrCreateInstance() succeeded[OVRPlugin][ERROR] [XRCMD][failure] [XR_ERROR_FORM_FACTOR_UNAVAILABLE]: xrGetSystem(instance, &systemGetInfo, &systemId), arvr\projects\integrations\ovrplugin\src\util\compositoropenxr.cpp:1332 (arvr\projects\integrations\ovrplugin\src\util\compositoropenxr.h:230)[OVRPlugin][INFO] xrGetSystem() failed, which might be caused by a temporarly HMD connectivity issue. xrInstance to be destroyed[OVRPlugin][ERROR] CompositorOpenXR::PreInitialize() returns failure (arvr\projects\integrations\ovrplugin\src\ovr_plugin_unityopenxr.cpp:59)[OVRPlugin][INFO] ProfilerSystem: verbose mode 0[OVRPlugin][INFO] OVRPlugin 1.79.0 ... preinitialized[OVRPlugin][INFO] Func_xrGetInstanceProcAddr: override xrCreateInstance[Subsystems] Loading plugin UnityOpenXR for subsystem OpenXR Display...
[XR] [26944] [10:56:36.841][Info   ] Available Layers: (0)
[OVRPlugin][INFO] Func_xrCreateInstance(0000026499CCCB28)[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unity Requested Extensions (18):[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_EXT_hand_tracking[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_FB_color_space[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_FB_display_refresh_rate[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_FB_hand_tracking_aim[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_FB_hand_tracking_capsules[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_FB_hand_tracking_mesh[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_FB_touch_controller_pro[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_KHR_D3D11_enable[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_KHR_composition_layer_color_scale_bias[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_KHR_composition_layer_cube[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_KHR_composition_layer_cylinder[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_KHR_composition_layer_depth[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_KHR_convert_timespec_time[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_KHR_visibility_mask[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_KHR_vulkan_enable[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_KHR_win32_convert_performance_counter_time[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_META_performance_metrics[OVRPlugin][INFO]   Name=XR_OCULUS_audio_device_guid[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_KHR_D3D12_enable[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_EXT_performance_settings[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_swapchain_update_state[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_swapchain_update_state_vulkan[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_foveation[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_foveation_configuration[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_foveation_vulkan[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_META_vulkan_swapchain_create_info[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_META_foveation_eye_tracked[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_KHR_composition_layer_equirect2[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_passthrough[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_triangle_mesh[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_passthrough_keyboard_hands[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_render_model[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_keyboard_tracking[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_scene[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_spatial_entity[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_spatial_entity_container[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_spatial_entity_query[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_spatial_entity_storage[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_spatial_entity_storage_batch[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_spatial_entity_sharing[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_spatial_entity_user[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_face_tracking[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_eye_tracking_social[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_body_tracking[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_touch_controller_proximity[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_haptic_amplitude_envelope[OVRPlugin][INFO] Unavailable OpenXR extension: XR_FB_haptic_pcm[OVRPlugin][INFO] Func_xrGetInstanceProcAddr: override xrPollEvent[OVRPlugin][INFO] Func_xrGetInstanceProcAddr: override xrWaitFrame[OVRPlugin][INFO] Func_xrGetInstanceProcAddr: override xrBeginFrame[OVRPlugin][INFO] Func_xrGetInstanceProcAddr: override xrEndFrame[OVRPlugin][INFO] Func_xrGetInstanceProcAddr: override xrSuggestInteractionProfileBindings[OVRPlugin][INFO] Func_xrGetInstanceProcAddr: override xrAttachSessionActionSets[OVRPlugin][INFO] Func_xrGetInstanceProcAddr: override xrSyncActions[OculusXRFeature] OnInstanceCreate: 17454747090945
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Oculus.XR.OculusXRFeature:OnInstanceCreate (ulong) (at Assets/Oculus/VR/Scripts/OculusXRFeature.cs:130)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.Features.OpenXRFeature:ReceiveNativeEvent (UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.Features.OpenXRFeature/NativeEvent,ulong) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/Features/OpenXRFeature.cs:610)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase:ReceiveNativeEvent (UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.Features.OpenXRFeature/NativeEvent,ulong) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/OpenXRLoader.cs:616)
UnityEngine.IntegratedSubsystemDescriptor`1<UnityEngine.XR.XRDisplaySubsystem>:Create ()
UnityEngine.IntegratedSubsystemDescriptor`1<UnityEngine.XR.XRDisplaySubsystem>:CreateImpl ()
UnityEngine.IntegratedSubsystemDescriptor:UnityEngine.ISubsystemDescriptor.Create ()
UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRLoaderHelper:CreateSubsystem<UnityEngine.XR.XRDisplaySubsystemDescriptor, UnityEngine.XR.XRDisplaySubsystem> (System.Collections.Generic.List`1<UnityEngine.XR.XRDisplaySubsystemDescriptor>,string) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@4.2.1/Runtime/XRLoaderHelper.cs:118)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase:CreateSubsystem<UnityEngine.XR.XRDisplaySubsystemDescriptor, UnityEngine.XR.XRDisplaySubsystem> (System.Collections.Generic.List`1<UnityEngine.XR.XRDisplaySubsystemDescriptor>,string) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/OpenXRLoader.cs:476)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase:CreateSubsystems () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/OpenXRLoader.cs:264)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase:InitializeInternal () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/OpenXRLoader.cs:237)
UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase:Initialize () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.openxr@1.4.2/Runtime/OpenXRLoader.cs:183)
UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRManagerSettings:InitializeLoaderSync () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@4.2.1/Runtime/XRManagerSettings.cs:190)
UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRGeneralSettings:InitXRSDK () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@4.2.1/Runtime/XRGeneralSettings.cs:175)
UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRGeneralSettings:AttemptInitializeXRSDKOnLoad () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.management@4.2.1/Runtime/XRGeneralSettings.cs:148)

(Filename: Assets/Oculus/VR/Scripts/OculusXRFeature.cs Line: 130)

[OVRPlugin][INFO] ovrp_UnityOpenXR_OnInstanceCreate(17454747090945)[OVRPlugin][INFO] Use D3D11 Renderer[OVRPlugin][INFO] OpenXR SDK version 1.0.22[OVRPlugin][INFO] Warning: unable to bind OpenXR entry xrGetD3D12GraphicsRequirementsKHR[OVRPlugin][INFO] OpenXR runtime name: Oculus, version 1.81.0[OVRPlugin][ERROR] [XRCMD][failure] [XR_ERROR_FORM_FACTOR_UNAVAILABLE]: xrGetSystem(instance, &systemGetInfo, &systemId), arvr\projects\integrations\ovrplugin\src\util\compositoropenxr.cpp:2199 (arvr\projects\integrations\ovrplugin\src\util\compositoropenxr.h:230)[OVRPlugin][INFO] xrGetSystem() failed, which might be caused by a temporarly HMD connectivity issue. xrInstance to be destroyed[OVRPlugin][ERROR] Plugin failed to initialize. (arvr\projects\integrations\ovrplugin\src\util\compositoropenxr.cpp:1049)[OVRPlugin][ERROR] Unable to create compositor: -1006 (arvr\projects\integrations\ovrplugin\src\ovr_plugin_unityopenxr.cpp:160)
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a UNKNOWN while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at UnityEngine.SubsystemDescriptorBindings:Create <0x000e0>
      at UnityEngine.IntegratedSubsystemDescriptor`1:Create <0x000a2>
      at UnityEngine.IntegratedSubsystemDescriptor`1:CreateImpl <0x0008a>
      at UnityEngine.IntegratedSubsystemDescriptor:UnityEngine.ISubsystemDescriptor.Create <0x0006c>
      at UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRLoaderHelper:CreateSubsystem <0x00509>
      at UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase:CreateSubsystem <0x000ca>
      at UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase:CreateSubsystems <0x0013a>
      at UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase:InitializeInternal <0x00992>
      at UnityEngine.XR.OpenXR.OpenXRLoaderBase:Initialize <0x004ba>
      at UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRManagerSettings:InitializeLoaderSync <0x003f2>
      at UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRGeneralSettings:InitXRSDK <0x0037a>
      at UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRGeneralSettings:AttemptInitializeXRSDKOnLoad <0x0019a>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_void <0x00184>
=================================================================
Received signal SIGSEGV
Obtained 2 stack frames
RtlLookupFunctionEntry returned NULL function. Aborting stack walk.
<Missing stacktrace information>
```

I appreciate your help :)
Cheers Fabian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a workaround to test in the editor without connecting the glasses. Disable "initialize XR On startup" in the XR Plug-in Management when only testing in the editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.Back-up your project.
2. Cut the Library folder and paste it on folders outside your project (desktop/anywhere)
3. Open the project. Unity will resolve the packages and open the project.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I have already tried that.

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/error-obtained-2-stack-frames-rtllookupfunctionentry.1382421/
This issue is already known, but they do not have a solution yet.